# using HTML and javascript or css or jquery technology

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, ms-word

What are the codes for making visited links activce and making unvisited links inactive?
  plz reply.
I have tried with javascript onckick functions, and css property
a:visited {color: red;}

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would add the css for anchors/links in the following order (often known as Love-Hate order):

a:link, a:visited {} 
a:hover, a:active {}